# Restful service URL parameter - Service Stack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, servicestack

Assume the endpoint `http://localhost/lookup?page=1&limit=10&term=testing` supported in Service Stack.

The request DTO is defined as

```
public class lookupRequest {
 public string term {get; set;}
 public pageRequest pageInfo {get; set;}
}
```

and pageRequest is defined as

```
public class pageRequest {
 public int page {get;set;}
 public int limit {get;set;}
}
```

so, having the service defined as:

```
public lookupResponse Any(lookupRequest request) { .. }
```

What else should be defined in order for the mapping work? I want to be able to pass limit and page as parameters in the URL and be mapped as pageRequest when the DTO is mapped.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You either need to flatten your DTO so that page and limit are a part of the DTO directly, or you need to modify your querystring parameters to qualify the parameters, such as `pageInfo.page` and `pageInfo.limit`.  If this is an acceptable answer, let me know and I'll move my comment to a response.  If you knew these options already and wanted instead a different solution, then I'll leave this as a comment and hope someone else can help more specifically.

Comment: How can I modify the querystring? Can you give an example, please?

Comment: `http://localhost/lookup?pageInfo.page=1&pageInfo.limit=10&term=testing`

Comment: Ok cool.  Escalated my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to flatten your DTO so that page and limit are a part of the DTO directly, or you need to modify your querystring parameters to qualify the parameters, such as pageInfo.page and pageInfo.limit.  An example of this method is: `http://localhost/lookup?pageInfo.page=1&pageInfo.limit=10&term=testing`